# file: symbol lookup error: file: undefined symbol: magic_setparam

Tags: command-line, files, file-command

My `file` command is broken.

```shell
$ file
file: symbol lookup error: file: undefined symbol: magic_setparam

$ which file 
/usr/local/bin/file

$ ldd $(which file)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc43fd000)
libmagic.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libmagic.so.1 (0x00007fe48cd2d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe48cb43000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe48c926000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe48cf86000)

$ # I have a file command in /usr/bin/ as well
$ # but the same thing happens, and the ldd output for it
$ # is identical to the one above
$ /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/file: undefined symbol: magic_setparam
```

I tried reinstalling the `file` command, as well as reinstalling `libmagic` (and `libmagic-dev`) but to no avail.

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) but I was experiencing the same issue on 18.04.

Comment: Please add output of `which file` and `ldd $(which file)` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove locally installed/compiled version of `libmagic` with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libmagic.so.1
```

and then call `file` again.